# How to create such tables in MS Word?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, word-2010

[image]

How to add such rables in MS Word 2010. This is known as table as I know, and used to incorporate SQL results in it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

read the article on making labels for mass mailing in word 2010 [click here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/make-labels-for-a-mass-mailing-HA101854798.aspx)